# how do I implement a formula into a c++ page based application (3 UITextField > UILabel)

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, uilabel, formula, viewcontroller

I am a new app developer and I need some assistance...

I am using xcode v4.5.1 and the app is for iphone.

Below is an image link from my MainStoryboard (View Controller - Me) that consists of 3 UITextField(s) and 1 UILabel which I have labeled as A-D (so you understand the formula format).

http://gyazo.com/332e5e43b827e60601fe8c40c543868a

My question is how can I implement this forumla so that it works.

```
Formula: A*(C/(A-B)) = D
```

What code will I need to implement and where should I put them.

Need as much help as possible, and all possible steps if you can help!

Comment: I don't understand why this is tagged as C++ when all iOS development is Objective C.

Comment: ^just fixed it, been a long day.

Answer (score 0):

hold control and drag from the label to the viewcontrollers header file so that it creates an outlet for the label that looks something like this `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;` (can be easier to do if you use the assistant editor, button is at the top right of xcode where it says 'editor')

do the same with the text fields, and then in a function you can go

```
- (void) someFunction {
    float A = [self.textfield1.text floatvalue];
    float B = [self.textfield2.text floatvalue];
    float C = [self.textfield3.text floatvalue];
    float result =  A*(C/(A-B));
    self.label.text = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:result];
}
```

you can hook up someFunction to a button or something similar to how you set the outlets for the label and text field. just make it an action instead of an outlet, unless you have some other way in mind.

ps. havnt tested this code at all so might need some tweaking

Comment: I have opened the assistant editor and the code sections thats opened to the right hand side is called UIViewController.h . Holding 'control' where exactly is the ViewController Header? Sorry I am new to developing but am trying to learn.

Comment: ah right, you need to make a new objective-c file in you project,  right click somewhere in the file list on the left, click ios cocoa touch, choose objective class, name it whatever you want, make sure the subclass is of type "UIViewController". 

once the file is made, click on your viewcontroller in the storyboard, click on the identity inspector at the top right. where it says custom class, put in the class name of the file you just made. then try what i said in the answer again

Comment: ok so i made an image file and am using it as an 'equals button'. I have done everything you have said but am stuck where you have written 'someFunction'. So.. what i have done is Control Dragged the image to the header file, and named it Go.

The header now reads... 
@property (strong, nonatomic IBOutlet UIImageView *Go;

What should I write instead of - (void) someFunction {

Comment: you wont be able to use an image as a button, use a UIButton, then in its properties (check the attribute tab) you can set its image (or background image) to something, maybe change its type to custom instead of round rect.

Comment: ok i will try, and should i change 'someFunction' to the name of the button?

Comment: when you control drag the button to the .h file, you will be able to name it when you put it there (remember to change it to an action not an outlet)

Comment: if i want it to do its thing when someone presses it, should i choose action Touch Down or Touch Up Inside?

Comment: just leave it as the default (touch up inside i think)

Comment: ok so i have done that, now the only problem i have is...
- (void) FillMeUp {

what should i do - the button i have made is called FillMeUp

Comment: il send you a pic of what ive done, i have renamed the button to Equalsfmu

Comment: ah, no you cant do that in the header, go look in the .m file to see if the actual function implementation is there, and paste the code in there. i think you need to find a tutorial on objective-c coding

Comment: you have 2 of the same function now, the top empty one is the right one because the dot in the bar just to the left of it shows that it is hooked up to the storyboard, so paste the stuff in there and delete the other function, cant have 2 functions with the same name. you need to change the `self.textfield1.text` to `self.A.text` and same with the other ones, rename the `float A` to something like `float a` and then change the variables in the equation below. `float Answer` should still be `float result` you must change the `self.label.text` to `self.Answer.text`

Comment: also you have a semicolon in the functions declaration which shouldnt be there

Comment: and i have just removed the semi-collon, but that has made all 3 floats sections (instead of 2) have the same errors.

Comment: you left off the .text after self.A also floatvalue should be floatValue ... you are lucky i am bored at work... :P

Comment: ok so the only error it has now, when i try to do run using iPhone 6.0 Simulator is... Storyboards are unavailable on iOS 4.3 and prior.

what do i need to do

Comment: if you click your project at the top of the file list and go to target, under the summary section, check that your deployment target is 6.0 or whatever, otherwise im not sure why it would be saying that

Comment: also, i dont know if this has anything to do with it, but this is the only other error...

gyazo.com/6d1d54c8c60f9e05a379d9dbcbc7438f

Comment: ah sorry, its meant to be [[NSNumber numberWithFloat:number] stringValue]

Comment: click on the breakpoints navigator at the top right, click the + button at the bottom left, add an new breakpoint for all exceptions, see if it stops at a more useful place when it crashes

Comment: should i tick the box 'options'?

www.gyazo.com/1d342edd49a3f45079f971124fb6b4dc

Comment: still gets stuck :O

http://gyazo.com/5d8734f13f243695a497530c1f59bb4d

i dont know what to do :(

Comment: hmm, www.pastebin.com your .m and your .h

Comment: of the view controller that i have made?

Comment: yeah, maybe i can spot something that is wrong. otherwise im not sure what you have done wrong to make it crash

Comment: hmm, nothing funny looking there, use NSLog(@"value %f", a); to print out the values of things, make sure a-b is not 0 otherwise you are dividing by 0 and that will crash. but other than that im not sure what all you have done to setup the project so it will be hard for me to tell what could have done. i would suggest you look for a nice tutorial that will explain everything from the begining

Comment: Im soo close but i am determined to fix this... In the storyboard, i have a viewcontroller which is the first screen when you open the app. There is a button on there which i have a triggered segue of 'push' linked to the View Controller i have made with you. When i push that, it crashes... does that help :L

Comment: i havnt written any code personally for this button, just made a push segue... should i write something for it?

Comment: that sounds fine to me, i cant really tell what could be wrong with it from here

Comment: i havn't implemented the NSLog... yet, should i try that?
I havn't done it yet because im not sure where you want me to place it.

Comment: well it sounds like you arent even getting to the point to run that function you have made so NSLog wont help. NSLog just prints out stuff in the console. maybe get rid of the first view controller for now and just test using the one

Comment: maybe start fresh with a new project now that you know what to do, i cant tell what could be going wrong.

Comment: ok, i might have to try that tomorrow then, i am extremely greatful though of everything you have done for me today. Fingers crossed that last peice of advise is all thats needed to get this through.

Comment: also i have just found this - could this be it?

www.gyazo.com/e3e1feac7fec70d875dbc7978ac992b4

Comment: go to target -> build phases. check that those image files are not under compile sources, and make sure they are under copy bundle resources

Comment: ok so they were in compile sources, and i have moved them to copy bundle resources... but the same message comes up

Comment: might need to clean the project: click product at the top -> clean

Comment: i have no idea how you managed to get things so messed up haha, um check under build settings in target that your architecture is set to armv7 and armv7s. otherwise i have no idea. i strongly suggest following a tutorial

Comment: Alright thank you anyway, i will try to start from scratch tomorrow, but otherwise il try find a suitable tutorial... do you have any in-mind?
Just i cant seem to find one thats appropriate.
but after the help you have been today, i should be able to implement the code created for the forumlas into the tutorial

Comment: can probably find a tutorial to start with here http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials

Comment: ok so i have re-done the whole thing this morning... AND IT WORKS! only thing i have left to ask, is.. how can i make it so when i press the button and the results show in the UILabel, so only show to 2 decimal places ... e.g. (now 21.333333) (want 21.33)